# Trigger Azure Functions from Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I am trying to determine the best practice for triggering an azure function from within Azure SQL Database.

I currently have a Azure Queue Function setup. Is there a way to insert into the queue from Azure SQL Database? Or when new data is inserted into a table?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Managed Instances, then you can use CLR Stored Procedures (Procedures written in c#) and do it.

If that's not the case, you can try the following:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1904724.aspx?Calling+a+Web+Service+from+T+SQL+Stored+Procedure+using+MSXML